# Why was the question about Nikolai Gogol's family name closed?

Tags: discussion, support, close-reasons, reopen-closed, specific-question

I've noticed that per-site metas are often littered with complaints/questions about question closure- so here's my own contribution to that genre.

I'd like to seek clarification on the closure of [this](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/71772/why-didnt-a-noble-family-change-their-last-name-from-a-kind-of-duck-to-somethin) question about Nikolai Gogol and his family name. It was closed for being primarily opinion-based, but I'm uncertain about the reasoning behind it.

First of all, prior to posting the question to the main site, the OP [created a meta-question](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4450/is-asking-about-the-reason-an-old-noble-family-chose-their-last-name-on-topic-he) to ask whether it would be on-topic. That, as far as I know, is *incredibly* rare. (If only all first-time askers did that!) Both of the answers to the meta-question indicate that, yes, asking about this would be on-topic.

Secondly, the question, when asked on the main site, was pretty well-received- it made the HNQ and got at least 6 upvotes (I don't have the see-vote-breakdown privilege yet). The question includes some prior research/effort on the OP's part and isn't one of those crappy one-line '[ask-and-dash](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/209913/what-do-you-call-a-qa-user-who-posts-a-question-but-never-checks-back)' posts.

The boilerplate close notice for opinion-based is '*This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations*'. But...the question *was* answered non-subjectively with two linked sources that explicitly examined what had been asked; it was answered with 'facts and citations' well before it was closed. Sure, the answer *kind of* refutes the premise, but it evidently satisfied the OP's doubts.

(I understand that it is currently in review and has two reopen votes)

---

Questions:

- What made it opinion-based?
- Is it salvageable?
- Are there any similar questions on this site that were closed for the 'q is subjective' reason that can be pointed to as precedent for this one?

(This post is a mix of challenging the closure and finding an explanation for it.)

Comment: I wasn't among the closers, but from just a glance at the title, I'm immediately thinking "Prestigious according to whom? What makes a word objectively prestigious?" It looks a lot to me like "Ducks are lame because I say so! It should have been something *I think is cooler* like a dragon or a rhino!"

Comment: @T.E.D. - The fact that Gogol's grandfather added that part *because it sounded more nobly* (["of  more noble Cossack ancestry"](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/71773/37321)) answers your `What makes a word objectively prestigious`: it sounded prestigious to the Kosaks or was imagined so by one who wanted to push forward his Ukrainian origin (possibly against a Polish or Russian one). The question seems legitimate, and got a very good answer too, which pleads in its favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few months of mire, the question has now been [re-opened](https://history.stackexchange.com/posts/71772/timeline#history_73269a1a-6a59-4037-a440-6749502bfc05).

I still don't have a clear picture as to *why* it was closed, but the reopening indicates community support for its on-topic-ness.